# how to make these images respond the way they need to?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to make six identical sized images align in two rows of 3 and then stack when the screen size changes. I'm getting the 3 x 2 stacking but it wont respond. I also want it to touch the edges of the window.

heres the html code:

```
<div class='container'>
    <a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" style="float: left; width: 33.3%; margin: 0px;" ></a>
    <a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" style="float: left; width: 33.3%; margin: 0px;" ></a>
    <a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" style="float: left; width: 33.3%; margin: 0px;" ></a>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByScraIkl4P9TUYzWm9vbDE0N1U/view?usp=sharing

I want this stacked underneath each other once the screen size drops.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **media queries**. This way you can adjust the style according to screen size. Of course you can write everything yourself, but I recommend that you take a look at **bootstrap**.

Sample:

```
/* extra small devices, phones */
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .container a img { width: 100%; float:none; }
}
/* small devices, tablets */
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .container a img { width: 50%; float: left; }
}
```

Using this css the image will take 100% or 50% width. Bootstrap provides classes for different screen sizes, ready for use to define how the elements will respond, show/hide etc. You can even reorder the elements. 
Strip the parts you dont need, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Images are 33% in width (so 3 will fit across), until screen size drops and they are set to 100%.

```
<div class='container'>
<a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" ></a>
<a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" ></a>
<a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" ></a>
<a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" ></a>
<a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" ></a> 
<a href="URL"><img src="images/photos/placeholder.jpg" ></a> 
</div>

.container img {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .container img {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/5zeLxbnt/

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will try this and let you know what happens. I will also try and make use of bootstrap.